# gevent 20.6.2 failure, exit code: 1, while installing bigchaindb on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: gevent, bigchaindb

I am attempting to install BigchainDB Version 2.2.2 on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine.
I entered the code

```
sudo pip3 install bigchaindb==2.2.2
```

The installation went part of the way before exiting and reporting the following, sorry, there is a lot of it;

```
Collecting gevent==20.6.2 (from bigchaindb-abci==1.0.5->bigchaindb==2.2.2)
  Using cached gevent-20.6.2.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]

      warning: src/gevent/_gevent_cgreenlet.pxd:112:33: Declarations should not be declared inline.
      
      Error compiling Cython file:
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      ...
      cdef load_traceback
      cdef Waiter
      cdef wait
      cdef iwait
      cdef reraise
      cpdef GEVENT_CONFIG
            ^
      ------------------------------------------------------------
      
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I can see that the error is related to gevent version 20.6.2.  I can see from the website that the latest version is 22.10.2.  I installed this version with ...

```
pip install gevent==22.10.2
```

This completed successfully.  I then rebooted, thinking that it might help!  haha
I restarted the bigchaindb installation and it failed at the same point.  I am guessing that the python script running the install is not checking for dependencies before it just blerts everything onto the machine!!!  Probably foolish of me to think that I could avoid the error like that anyway.

Many of the 60 lines of output reported this;

```
The 'DEF' statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future Cython version. Consider using global variables, constants, and in-place literals instead. See https://github.com/cython/cython/issues/4310
```

So, my questions are these:

1. Has anyone else experienced the same error?
2. If so, how was it resolved, please?
3. If not, is somebody knowledgeable willing to work with me to resolve the issue, please?

Thank you

Graham

It would be great if BigChainDB did not use old versions of libraries, I expect they would update their script when new libraries are available and tested.

Comment: 12/Jun/2023:  I installed libevent-dev using  `sudo apt-get install libevent-dev`as was suggested in another  reported error associated with gevent. However, this did not change the error I received when I repeated my attempt to install BigchainDB

Comment: I have built machines with Ubuntu 23.04, 22.10, 22.04 & 18.04 on them, installed python versions  to between 3.7 to 3.10,  Always the same result               `Collecting gevent==20.6.2 (from bigchaindb-abci==1.0.5->bigchaindb)
  Downloading gevent-20.6.2.tar.gz (5.8 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.8/5.8 MB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]`

Comment: Problem resolved: I installed Ubuntu 18.04.7 LTS on a machine, it has natively Python 3.8 installed. I ran the following' 1. `sudo apt install -y python3-pip libssl-dev`  2. `sudo pip3 install -U pip` & 3.  `sudo pip3 install bigchaindb==2.2.2` and it installed without issues

Answer (score 0):

This is a known compactibility issue, to solve this, here are the dependencies you need.

**markupsafe - v2.0.1 

itsdangerous -  v2.0.1 

werkzeug - v2.0.1 

Jinja2 - v3.0.3 

gevent - v20.6.2 

greenlet - v0.4.16**

If encountered any issue installing PyNCl, use this (Infact this method works perfectly for me, so I'd suggest you try installing through SODIUM):

```
wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/libsodium-1.0.18-stable.tar.gz
tar -xvf libsodium-1.0.18-stable.tar.gz libsodium-stable
cd libsodium-stable/
./configure
make -j
make install
SODIUM_INSTALL=system pip3 install PyNaCl==1.1.2 bigchaindb werkzeug==2.0.1 markupsafe==2.0.1 itsdangerous==2.0.1 Jinja2==3.0.3 gevent==20.6.2 greenlet==0.4.16
```

Finally, Run:

```
bigchaindb configure
bigchaindb -y drop
bigchaindb init
bigchaindb start
```